# How to wake up ios from my app?

Tags: ios, idle-timer

In my game, the sprites blink when iOS goes into idle. To fix this issue, I set idle timer disabled, but the app can still get idle in some scenarios, for instance, the app get sleep and then switch back by users.

Is there any way I can wake up ios proactively with some API?

Comment: You can't just pause the timer?

Comment: yes, anyother I can do?

Comment: With private APIs, maybe. With ones you are able to use, definitely not. Apple does not want to let any app randomly turn on/wake up/unlock because that would be a security and a battery issue. How would you feel if an app stopped you from turning off your phone?

Comment: Please further explain the issue of "sprites blink".

Comment: problem like this: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/sprite-is-blinking/

Answer (score 1):

There is **no way** of doing it other than:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

Only the user can control when your app is sent to background / foreground / sleep.